# TextBox's Text is moving slightly when toggling Enabled: Font and Font size changes

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, textbox, drawing

In my application, I have Custom TextBox Control. Its Text seems to be moving when I change the `Enabled` property.

1. I don't understand what cause this.
2. I will be changing `TextAlign`, `AutoSize`, `Enabled`, and `Font` properties

I've tried using `TextRenderer.DrawText()`: it seems to fix some issues but when I change to certain Font and Font size, the Text is moving again (for example, setting ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt).

I have searched the site and read the following but didn't seem to understand properly:

[Using Graphics.DrawString to Simulate TextBox rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045641/using-graphics-drawstring-to-simulate-textbox-rendering)

[How do I use DrawString without trimming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920024/how-do-i-use-drawstring-without-trimming)

[Graphics.DrawString vs TextRenderer.DrawText?Which can Deliver Better Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283631/graphics-drawstring-vs-textrenderer-drawtextwhich-can-deliver-better-quality)

---

Here are some screenshots:

**ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt And TextAlign Center and e.Graphics.DrawString**

[↓↓ Enabled ↓↓](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU3j7.png)

[↓↓ Disabled ↓↓](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03MNl.png)

[comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggk6v.png)

**ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt And TextAlign Center and TextRenderer.DrawText**

[↓↓ Enabled ↓↓](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rllc6.png)

[↓↓ Disabled ↓↓](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVWMz.png)

[comparison (text seems to be slightly elongated when disabled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv3FO.png)

Original post of my code
https://devlights.hatenablog.com/entry/20070523/p1

This is my Custom Control code do far:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class CustomEnabledStateTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CustomEnabledStateTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AutoSize = false;
    }

    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get { return base.AutoSize; }
        set { base.AutoSize = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, !this.Enabled);
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
        {
            if (this.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Center)
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            }
            else if (this.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            }
            else
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            }

            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            {
                //MS UI Gothic, 8pt --> not OK
                //MS UI Gothic, 9pt --> OK
                //MS UI Gothic, 10pt --> OK
                //MS UI Gothic, 11pt --> OK
                //MS UI Gothic, 12pt --> not OK
                e.Graphics.DrawString(
                    base.Text, base.Font, brush, new Rectangle(-1, 1, base.Width, base.Height), sf);

                //ＭＳ ゴシック, 8pt --> not OK
                //ＭＳ ゴシック, 9pt --> not OK
                //ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt --> not OK
                //ＭＳ ゴシック, 12pt --> not OK
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(
                //    base.Text, base.Font, brush, new Rectangle(-1, 1, base.Width, base.Height), sf);

                //ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt --> not OK
                //TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.Internal);
            }

            if (this.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        customEnabledStateTextBox1.Text = "2021/04/04";
        customEnabledStateTextBox1.Size = new Size(88, 20);
        customEnabledStateTextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        customEnabledStateTextBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customEnabledStateTextBox1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customEnabledStateTextBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

---

**Update 1**

I have Changed my code according to Answer provided by Jimi
And tested it and it fix some issues but the problem still exits when I used
ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt And fount out that in both MS UI Gothic, 10pt AND  ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt cases , Text is moving slightly downward.My application use ＭＳ ゴシック 7pt~12pt.So I have to show  10pt correctly.
I haven't tested with other Fonts though.
Please Help.

Sorry that I didn`t provide .Net framework  before
I am be using

```
 .NET Framework 3.5
 BorderStyle None
```

Test Case

```
MS UI Gothic, 8pt-- > OK
MS UI Gothic, 9pt-- > OK
MS UI Gothic, 10pt-- > not OK
MS UI Gothic, 11pt-- > OK
MS UI Gothic, 12pt-- > OK

ＭＳ ゴシック, 8pt-- > OK
ＭＳ ゴシック, 9pt-- > OK
ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt-- > not OK
ＭＳ ゴシック, 12pt-- > OK
```

Here are Screenshots for

**ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt And TextAlign Center and BorderStyle None  andTextRenderer.DrawText**
[image: Enabled]
[image: Disabled]
[image: Comparison]

**MS UI Gothic, 10pt And TextAlign Center and BorderStyle None and TextRenderer.DrawText**
[image: Enabled]
[image: Disabled]
[image: Comparison]

Updated Code below :
I have tested it in both .Net Framework 3.5 And 4.8

CustomEnabledStateTextBox :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormTest1
{
    public partial class CustomEnabledStateTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public override bool AutoSize
        {
            get { return base.AutoSize; }
            set { base.AutoSize = value; }
        }

        public CustomEnabledStateTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AutoSize = false;
        }

        
        protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            //>>>Change 1
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, !Enabled);
            UpdateStyles();
            //>>>Change 1
            base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
        }

        //>>>Change 1
        protected override void OnBorderStyleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBorderStyleChanged(e);
            if (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
            {
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            }
        }
        //>>>Change 1



        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
            {

                if (this.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                {
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                }
                else if (this.TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                {
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                }
                else
                {
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                }

                //>>>Change 1
                var rect = ClientRectangle;
                if (BorderStyle != BorderStyle.None) rect.Inflate(-1, -1);

                var alignment = TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Left
                              ? TextFormatFlags.Left : (TextFormatFlags)((int)TextAlign ^ 3);

                var flags = TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | alignment;
                //>>>Change 1

                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
                {
                    //MS UI Gothic, 8pt --> not OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 9pt --> OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 10pt --> OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 11pt --> OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 12pt --> not OK
                    //e.Graphics.DrawString(
                    //    base.Text, base.Font, brush, new Rectangle(-1, 1, base.Width, base.Height), sf);

                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 8pt --> not OK
                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 9pt --> not OK
                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt --> not OK
                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 12pt --> not OK
                    //e.Graphics.DrawString(
                    //    base.Text, base.Font, brush, new Rectangle(-1, 1, base.Width, base.Height), sf);

                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt --> not OK
                    //TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.Internal);

                    //TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ForeColor, flags);

                    //>>>Change 1
                    //MS UI Gothic, 8pt --> OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 9pt --> OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 10pt --> not OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 11pt --> OK
                    //MS UI Gothic, 12pt --> OK

                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 8pt --> OK
                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 9pt --> OK
                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt --> not OK
                    //ＭＳ ゴシック, 12pt --> OK

                    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, rect, ForeColor, flags);
                    //>>>Change 1

                }

                if (this.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
                }

                //>>>Change 1
                base.OnPaint(e);
                //>>>Change 1
            }
        }


 
    }
}
```

CustomEnabledStateTextBoxSO :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormTest1
{
    public partial class CustomEnabledStateTextBoxSO : TextBox
    {
        public override bool AutoSize
        {
            get { return base.AutoSize; }
            set { base.AutoSize = value; }
        }

        public CustomEnabledStateTextBoxSO()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AutoSize = false;
        }

        protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, !Enabled);
            UpdateStyles();
            base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnBorderStyleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBorderStyleChanged(e);
            if (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
            {
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var rect = ClientRectangle;
            if (BorderStyle != BorderStyle.None) rect.Inflate(-1, -1);

            var alignment = TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Left
                          ? TextFormatFlags.Left : (TextFormatFlags)((int)TextAlign ^ 3);

            var flags = TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | alignment;

            //MS UI Gothic, 8pt-- > OK
            //MS UI Gothic, 9pt-- > OK
            //MS UI Gothic, 10pt-- > not OK
            //MS UI Gothic, 11pt-- > OK
            //MS UI Gothic, 12pt-- > OK

            //ＭＳ ゴシック, 8pt-- > OK
            //ＭＳ ゴシック, 9pt-- > OK
            //ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt-- > not OK
            //ＭＳ ゴシック, 12pt-- > OK
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, rect, ForeColor, flags);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Test Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormTest1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Left Side
            customEnabledStateTextBox1.Text = "2021/04/04";
            customEnabledStateTextBox1.Size = new Size(88, 20); //size will change if i set Autosize true
            customEnabledStateTextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            customEnabledStateTextBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            //Right Side
            customEnabledStateTextBoxSO1.Text = "2021/04/04";
            customEnabledStateTextBoxSO1.Size = new Size(88, 20); //size will change if i set Autosize true
            customEnabledStateTextBoxSO1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            customEnabledStateTextBoxSO1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customEnabledStateTextBox1.Enabled = true;
            customEnabledStateTextBoxSO1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customEnabledStateTextBox1.Enabled = false;
            customEnabledStateTextBoxSO1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes to the text rendering should get you close to what you're expecting.

- Use [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer) to draw the text
- Add `TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl` and `TextFormatFlags.NoPadding` to the [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags) used in `TextRenderer.DrawText()` (see the Docs about these two)
- Override `OnBorderStyleChanged()` to replace the `FixedSingle` style with `Fixed3D` when the Control is custom-drawn. This is what the base class (TextBoxBase) does, otherwise you get the default internal border that shrinks the Win32 Control's Client area.
- Inflate the Control's ClientRectangle by `-1` pixel when `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D`.

I added [UpdateStyles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.updatestyles) after the `SetStyle()` call: this forces the new Styles and also causes the Control to repaint itself.

---

Note that setting a Font that doesn't support all CodePoint (simplified: the Unicode chars in your Text) used when setting the Text of a control, may cause a Font Fallback.
In practice, the System will select a mapped surrogate Font that replaces the Control's Font. This happens *transparently* and without notice.
A different Graphic renderer can behave in a different manner in similar situations.

See the notes here:
[How can a Label control display Japanese characters properly when the Font used doesn't support this language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612395/7444103)

Somewhat different in a RichTextBox Control (the .Net base class is the same, but the Win32 Control is quite different):
[Some Alt keys changes my RichTextBox font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451303/7444103)

Also, quite recently, all Asian Font rendering and UI presentation has been modified to better handle its characteristics. So the .Net version in use can also change the behavior.
The code here is tested with `.Net Framework 4.8`.

---

```
public partial class CustomEnabledStateTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CustomEnabledStateTextBox() => this.AutoSize = false;

    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, !Enabled);
        UpdateStyles();
        base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnBorderStyleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBorderStyleChanged(e);
        if (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle) BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }

    private TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | 
                                    TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var rect = ClientRectangle;
        if (BorderStyle != BorderStyle.None) rect.Inflate(-1, -1);

        var alignment = TextAlign == HorizontalAlignment.Left
                      ? TextFormatFlags.Left : (TextFormatFlags)((int)TextAlign^ 3);

        flags |= alignment;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, rect, ForeColor, flags);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it fix some of the issues  but ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt problem still exits. I have updated my post.

Comment: MS UI Gothic is one of the Japanese fallback Fonts in my language (en-US): it's usually hidden and only used as FallBack Font surrogate, as described here. I've tested this Font and it work exactly as all the other Fonts I've tested (yes, I've tested 10pt). As also mentioned, you need .Net Framework 4.8 or .Net Core 3.1 or .Net 5 for properly testing.

Comment: Yes, i have installed and tested in .NetFramework 4.8.and i change the AutoScaleMode too. Still the problem exits on my environment. my display language is Japanese though.i have checked registry too. it has  MS UI Gothic. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink   maybe i should just avoid 10pt . Thank you Jimi

Comment: Yes, of course if your System language is Japanese, then MS UI Gothic can be set as *visible* (not hidden because used as Fallback Font as in mine). -- You should be *allowed* to use 10pt. I'm not sure why you have a problem with that size, since, as mentioned, I've tested it (un-hiding the Font) and 10pt has the same result as the other sizes (10pt is actually 9.75pt). Maybe let me know what System and version this code has been tested in, so I can try to replicate the issue.

Comment: SystemInfo:Windows 10 Pro, OS build 19042.1110, Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0,System Language is set to Japanese and no other language is installed. AND tested on both .Net Framework  4.8 and 3.5. Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I changed the ＭＳ ゴシック, 10pt to new font(control.FontFamily, 10.2f) and the problem resolve. Thank you.